# MySQL tabelas temporarias

Tags: php, mysql

Estou aqui a estudar as tabelas temporárias do MySQL, e estou a criar umas tabelas temporárias. Estou a usar o `mysqli`, segundo o [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), as tabelas temporárias apagam-se após o fecho da conexão.

Mas a verdade é que isso não me acontece, as tabelas temporárias são apagadas mesmo quando não faço o *close* da conexão. Será mesmo assim o comportamento ou eu é que estou a meter água?

**Código PHP:**

```
$mysqli     = new mysqli(HOST, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, DATA_BASE);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, CHARSET);

$sql_create = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...";     
$mysqli->query($sql_create));

//$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Acho que precisa um pouco mais de detalhes no exemplo. Como você está pretendendo usar a tabela? É tudo no mesmo script? lembrando que o PHP vai fechar a conexão de qualquer jeito no fim do script.

Comment: Vi este artigo outro dia ajuda ?   http://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/mysql/mysql-e-tabelas-temporarias/

Comment: @Bacco Então não há forma de eu verificar se as tabelas foram criadas? Era mais para debug, só para ter a certeza que as tabelas eram criadas e se o conteúdo que eu insiro é inserido.

Comment: @Motta vou ver, parece interessante.

Comment: @JorgeB. dá, mas você tem que verificar no mesmo script. Por exemplo, fazendo um select nesta mesma tabela logo abaixo da criação dela, no mesmo arquivo PHP (e antes do close, pois você tem que aproveitar a conexão que já está aberta).

Comment: @Bacco parece me que seja isso mesmo. Não sei se a pergunta é sequer pertinente para manter aberta, mas se quiseres fazer a resposta.

Comment: @Bacco é isso ai funcionou direitinho :)

Comment: @JorgeB. poste aí uma versão bem simplificada como resposta, pode ser útil para outras pessoas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que o PHP fecha a conexão de qualquer jeito no fim do *script*, por isso se quisermos verificar se estamos a fazer tudo bem podemos por exemplo, fazer um `select` nesta mesma tabela logo abaixo da criação dela, no mesmo arquivo PHP (e antes do *close*, pois temos que aproveitar a conexão que já está aberta).

Exemplo:

```
   if ($result = $mysqli->query("select * from TABELA"))
   {
      while($obj = $result->fetch_object())
      {
         echo "Campo1: ".$obj->campo1."; ";
         echo "Campo2: ".$obj->campo2;"; ";
         ...
         echo "<br>";
      }
   }
   $result->close();
```

Fonte: [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)

Comment: Seria legal, a hora que puder, você acrescentar um trecho de código nem simplificado, mas que funcione, para servir de exemplo. :) Agradeço, mas nao precisa do crédito não, só dei a dica.

Comment: Feito, claro que precisa de crédito :)